# how to avoid data from one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query which is join of  two tables as you can see From the result I want to avoid data from one column. From below result set I want to avoid Other row

```
IncidentCategory             No_Incident

Near Miss                  25
Road Events               129
Service Strike                150
Other                         Null  


SELECT BT.Name AS IncidentCategory, SUM(IR.ID) AS No_Incident  
From BBTypes BT LEFT JOIN  
     IncidentReports IR  
     ON BT.ID = IR.BbType AND
        IR.WbsElementId =  23 
GROUP BY BT.Name                
ORder By BT.Name DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean "avoid data from one column"?  Just add `where incidentCategory <> 'Other'` if you don't want it in the output.

Comment: Can't you just do a RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT

Comment: Its not only Null thing, lets say I don't want to show other row.        @Gordon Linoff I already tried Where
IncidentCategory <> 'Other' but I got an error, Invalid column name 'IncidentCategory'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
where BT.Name <> 'Other'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query you use GROUP BY so it is better to use HAVING COUNT to boost your query performance.

HAVING COUNT(IR.ID)>0 is avoid null row in No_Incident column.

```
SELECT BT.Name AS IncidentCategory, SUM(IR.ID) AS No_Incident  
From BBTypes BT LEFT JOIN  
     IncidentReports IR  
     ON BT.ID = IR.BbType AND
        IR.WbsElementId =  23 
GROUP BY BT.Name       
HAVING COUNT(IR.ID)>0         
ORDER BY BT.Name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to ignore the `NULL` row, use `inner join` instead of an outer join:

```
SELECT BT.Name AS IncidentCategory, SUM(IR.ID) AS No_Incident  
From BBTypes BT JOIN  
     IncidentReports IR  
     ON BT.ID = IR.BbType AND
        IR.WbsElementId =  23 
GROUP BY BT.Name                
ORder By BT.Name DESC;
```

Doing the sum of an `id` column seems strange.  I am guessing that you really want `count()` instead:

```
SELECT BT.Name AS IncidentCategory, COUNT(IR.ID) AS No_Incident  
From BBTypes BT JOIN  
     IncidentReports IR  
     ON BT.ID = IR.BbType AND
        IR.WbsElementId =  23 
GROUP BY BT.Name                
ORder By BT.Name DESC;
```

Comment: ts not only Null thing, lets say I don't want to show other row.